# how to make vim show ^M and substitute it

Tags: regex, vim

my vim show tab as --->, but does not show windows ^M character.

And , how substitute it in vim.

renew ============

I check my vimrc it is  set fileformat=unix
but when I open a dos file set ff is dos

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Vim does show ^M except in one case: if the *fileformat=dos* then it will not show a trailing crlf.

You can find out which format (unix or dos) you have by typing `:set` and you can get rid of the ^M in the crlf by just changing the format (`:set fileformat=unix`) and then writing out the file.

If you have a ^M in the middle of the line, then you should be able to see it, even in a `fileformat=dos` file, and you can pattern match it with `\r`. (Oddly, the syntax for subsituting a newline is a `\r` in the replacement part of the sub, so the way one changes ^M to ^N is by the not-at-all-a-noop `:s/\r/\r/`.)

Comment: my vimrc set ff=unix, but when I open a dos file, ff is dos, when I set ff=unix in vim command, it does not show it anyway, when I quit, vim told me I did not save, so I save it, it looks subsituted.

Comment: The statement "Vim does show ^M except in one case: if the *fileformat=dos* then it will not show a trailing crlf" is incorrect -- Vim does show `^M` even when `fileformat` is set to `dos`. It does so for me.

Comment: If doesn't work for me. I need to `set ffs=unix` to enable it.

Answer (score 87):

### Display CRLF as ^M:

:e ++ff=unix

### Substitute CRLF for LF:

:setlocal ff=unix
:w
:e

Comment: Could you, please, add an explanation (in a separate paragraph) what each line does.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov  NoToR hasn't logged on since 2012, but perhaps someone else could edit the answer to give more of an explanation?

Comment: `:e ++ff=unix` uses the `:edit` command to load the file again from disk, specifically with the unix file format: `++ff=unix`.

`:setlocal` I believe sets a local options just for this vim window, ensuring that file format is set to unix: `ff=unix`.

`:w` writes the file to disk.

`:e` loads the file from disk again to display the current state of the file.

Answer (score 9):

To remove  ^M characters from you vim:
In command mode type

```
%s/
```

followed by

```
ctrl+v and Enter.
```

It should then look like :

```
%s/^M
```

Lastly  replace with blank character :

```
%s/^M//g
```

Comment: Great! @anonymous

Answer (score 8):

vim is autodetecting the fileformat and switching modes to match (take a look at `set ff`)

If you want to force it to open in a particular mode, toss a `+ff=unix`(to show the ^M) or `+ff=dos` in your command line to open it in that mode. If you're on a windows box, just try `:e ++ff=unix` after opening the file.

If you're trying to just strip those characters out, you can open it in one mode, set the ff to what you want, and then save the file. Check out `:h ff` for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Old fashioned way - works even in vi:

```
    vim -b filename
    :%s/^V^M//g
    :x
```

Explanations:

- vim -b opens vim in binary mode, all control characters will be visible
- vi doesn't have -b option but then again vi doesn't need it, it will show ^M by default
- :%s is search replace - we are replacing ^M with nothing
- You have to type Control-V Control-M in a sequence, you can keep Control down all the time, or you can release it and press again - both works.
- ^V will disappear, only ^M will stay. ^V means insert next character literally (try pressing Escape after ^V). Without it Control-M would just mean Carriage Return - or same as pressing Enter.
- Don't try to copy ^M with a mouse, it will break it into two characters ^ and M and it will mean search for M at the beginning of the line.
- g means global - if you have ^M only on end of line you don't really need it
- :x means save and exit - almost no one is using it

Comment: `vim -b` show `^M`, but `%s/^V^M//g` not work for me on Arch Linux.

Comment: dos2unix work for me, I fixed the issue using `find .  | xargs dos2unix`

Comment: Thanks for -b, finally, could see all the ^M characters!

Answer (score 4):

You can view all terminal linefeeds and carriage returns by enabling the list feature: `:set list`.

ou can type them literally into match and substitution commands with <kbd>^V</kbd>: e.g. to convert all `^M`s to `CR`, you could do: `:%s/^V^M/CR/g` (type a literal <kbd>^V</kbd> followed by a literal <kbd>^M</kbd>).

Comment: When in DOS mode, the carriage-return characters do not appear using ":set list".  Or rather, they appear as the normal "$" showing end-of-line.  Furthermore, you can't do a literal substitution using ^V^M.