# Highlight ^M(CR) in vim

Tags: vim, carriage-return, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a way to highlight ^M(CR) in vim.

Comment: You should consult the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters

Answer (score 1):

Make sure fileformat is set=unix or mac mine is:

```
set fileformats=unix,mac
```

If it is DOS you will not see it

I have a mapping in my `.vimrc` that will remove them, but this response here explains it best.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852892/2869058

You can view all terminal line endings and characters by enabling

```
:set list
```

one way you can highlight them is like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on

set list listchars=trail:_
set listchars=tab:·\ ,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«
:highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=yellow
```